# Dereferencing pointer in LLVM-IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing llvm ir, but I'm having trouble dereferencing pointers.
How do I determine the internal type of a pointer and dereference a pointer?
example:

```
    let a i32 = 0;
    let b *i32 = &a;
    *b = 1;
    let c i32 = 0;
    b = &c;
    *b = 1;
```

i want to write code to handle all of these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to tell LLVM the type, typically based on information in your the abstract syntax tree representing your program.

LLVM's pointers are just that, pointers, as is common in assembly languages. The [store](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StoreInst.html) constructor makes an instruction that writes as many bits as you supply in the `value` parameter, the [load](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoadInst.html) constructor takes a type parameter and the result will have that type (and read the correct number of bits from memory), the [GEP::Create](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html#acc1696cc0fcd0bb9837c65028fce9479) function takes the pointee type as the first parameter and does its calculations based on that, etc.

LLVM up to version 9 (IIRC) was different, but I don't want to go into that story now.